# How many animal species are larger than humans?

Tags: zoology

I sometimes think about just how huge humans are in comparison to most animals. Even compared to a squirrel, which is really a pretty large organism in the grand scheme of things, humans are hulking giants.

I know humans are classified as [megafauna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megafauna), but we're neither the smallest nor the largest animals in that group.

**How many animal species currently exist where the average adult individual is more massive than the average adult human?**

Sources that cite other measures of size, like height or length, might be useful, but I would expect the focus to be on mass.

Obviously, new species are being discovered all the time, and we don't have exhaustive measurements for every species, but considering how few megafauna there are, I would expect a fairly accurate estimate to be possible.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Larger in term of distance between the two extremities of the body? Larger in weights? or in volume? Would Placentonema gigantissima (9 meters long, 2.5 cm in diameter) be bigger than a human? Are you talking only about extant species?

Comment: In the last sentence you rephrase your question "How many different species are actually larger than us", do you mean animal species (as specified in the title) or any species? In many non-animal species, the concept of individual might be hard to define. There's a fungi who covers an area of almost 9 square km in eastern Oregon.

Comment: Depending on the exact formulation of your question I think that an exhaustive list might be very long. But I guess someone could come up with a rough estimate of the number of species.

Comment: Echoing remi.b's point - unless this question is narrowed down it is very broad.

Comment: @Remi.b I definitely mean animal species, I don't know why anyone would think I would suddenly be referring to fungi. I've clarified that. I'm referring to extant species. I assumed that mass would be the implicit measure for size, but I've clarified that as well. I didn't ask for a list anywhere, just a number. Listing them would be helpful, but not necessary.

Comment: I think this question is not broad at all, there have been plenty of serious estimates of species richness ~ size relationships: http://www.life.illinois.edu/ib/451/May%20(1988).pdf

Comment: Yes, the answer is a single number. That's about as far from broad as you can get.

Comment: EOL knows about (268 species of mammals with a mass >= 80.7kg)[http://eol.org/data_search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&taxon_concept_id=1642&attribute=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FVT_0001259&taxon_name=Mammalia&min=80.6&max=&unit=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FUO_0000009&sort=desc&commit=Search] and (5,701 species of mammals with a mass <= 80.7kg)[http://eol.org/data_search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&taxon_concept_id=1642&attribute=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FVT_0001259&commit=Search&taxon_name=Mammalia&min=&max=80.7&unit=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FUO_0000009&sort=desc]

Comment: @Gaurav Well that's pretty neat. I was not familiar with that website. I don't know how exhaustive EOL's data is, but that looks like the core of an answer to me.

Comment: Looks like 80.7 kg is the average for humans in North America. Google says the average for humans worldwide is 62 kg, but EOL has it listed at 68.8 kg.

Comment: I agree the question is definitely no too broad. I first voted to close as unclear, it is now clear and I am voting to reopen.

Comment: Humans weigh 62 kg on average. According to https://www.catalogueoflife.org/col/info/totals, there are 91 cetacean species, 80 of which are larger than humans.